# Show this relation for the support of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $\Theta\subseteq C^0(E,E)$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $G\in\Theta'$.

The "support" $\operatorname{supp}G$ of $G$ is the set of all $x\in E$ such that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a $\theta\in\Theta$ with $\operatorname{supp}\theta\subseteq U$ and $\langle G,\theta\rangle\ne0$.

Now, if $\Omega\subseteq E$ and $\langle G,\theta\rangle=0$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$ with $\left.\theta\right|_\Omega=0$, can we infer that $\operatorname{supp}G\subseteq\Omega$?

Comment: Is the definition of support really correct? It looks more like the complement of the support.

Comment: @md2perpe There was a typo; it should be $\langle G,\theta\rangle\ne0$.

Comment: Good. Then it's the same as the one I've learnt: the support is the complement of the biggest open set on which $G=0.$

Comment: @md2perpe And do you see how can we can infer that $\operatorname{supp}G\subseteq\Omega$?

Comment: I think that you also miss $\operatorname{supp}\theta \subset U$ in your definition of $\operatorname{supp}G.$

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\theta\in\Theta$ such that $\operatorname{supp}\theta \subseteq \complement\Omega.$ Then $\theta|_\Omega=0$ so $\langle G, \theta \rangle=0.$ This means that $\operatorname{supp}G  \subseteq \complement(\complement\Omega)=\Omega$ according to the definition of support that I have learnt:
$$\operatorname{supp}G=\complement \bigcup \{ \text{open } U\subseteq E \mid \langle G, \theta \rangle=0 \text{ for all $\theta\in\Theta$ such that $\operatorname{supp}\theta \subset U$} \},$$
which I think is equivalent to your definition
$$
\operatorname{supp}G=\{x\in E \mid \forall \text{ open } U\ni x \, \exists \theta\in\Theta \text{ with } \operatorname{supp}\theta\subset U \text{ s.t. } \langle G, \theta \rangle \neq 0\}.
$$